# Codeigniter Tank Auth Activation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with the the tank auth email activation functionality. Using Codeigniter 2.1.0 and Tank Auth 1.0.9

If I click the activation link within the email that is sent when you register, it opens in a new window and appears to run the auth controller activate() function twice. The activation is run in the database because I can see it update.. but because the function is run twice it shows the session message "The activation code you have entered is incorrect or expired". This isn't ideal from a user perspective and will cause confusion with the end user.

however, If I copy the activation url from the email and copy paste it into the window I initially registered in it works as it should and displays the correct session message.

What would be causing the controller to act up when the link in the email is clicked and a new browser window tries to run the activation url??

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

```
$routes[]

.htaccess rewrite

javascript redirect

php header()

session death

hidden F5 key under your chair
```